# Running composer install not working with Jenkins in a microservices architecture

Tags: laravel, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, composer-php, lumen

I am automating a microservices architecture with a Jenkins pipeline and having this issue although the file `composer.json` exists in that folder

> C:\Program Files
> (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\C2Project\C2\autority-service>composer update
> Composer could not find a composer.json file in C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\C2Project\C2\autority-service
> To initialize a project, please create a composer.json file as described in the https://getcomposer.org/ "Getting Started" section

here is the concerned jenkins stage:

```
 stage('Build autority-service'){ steps { dir('C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Jenkins\\workspace\\C2Project\\C2\\autority-service') {
    bat "sudo composer update" 
    bat "sudo composer dump-autoload"
    bat "sudo composer install"
    sh "php artisan key:generate"
    bat "php artisan cache:clear"
    bat "php artisan config:clear"
    bat "php artisan migrate"
    bat "php artisan db:seed" } } }
```

Can anyone please help me fix this issue?

Comment: Please share more details. For example, does the folder contain a `composer.json`? Also, why are you running `composer update`?

Comment: First I said I'm running composer install and I already said that the file exists in that folder

Comment: The code you've posted shows `composer update`,  and if there was a file, Composer would not claim that there is no file

Comment: Sorry that's true I just added that when it didn't work and still it doesn't

Comment: I wanted to automate building the project with packages installations in each micro-service, I added the concerned stage of the pipeline to my question

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. Also, please share what you've tried to resolve the problem. Also, running `composer update` in a CI does  not sound like a good idea to me - why not use the dependencies from `composer.lock`?

Comment: I tried to modify permissions on `composer.json` with `bat "chmod a+r composer.json"` but still not working. I also tried by adding `checkout msc`, how to change the use of the dependencies to `composer.lock`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this issue by adding a `composer.phar` file because Jenkins couldn't recognize the `composer.json` file as they are similar with this command line `curl -sS getcomposer.org/installer | php` then installed composer on the Jenkins server using the `composer.phar` file `php composer.phar install`